# Maven, how to inherit properties to modules

Tags: java, maven

In maven, is it possible to inherit configuration from POM to it's modules, without declaring it as a parent in the submodule POM?

More specifically, I would like to inherit the version number from the POM containing the modules. If I get it from declaring the parent, I have to hard code the parent version number to each module. If I update the parent POM, I must update all the module POM's too. This is the duplication of information I would like to avoid for maintenance reasons. I would like to have all the modules same version number as parent, and define the version *only* in the parent.

Comment: *If I update the parent POM, I must update all the module POM's too* only if you want that change to propagate to all the submodules **inheriting** form it.

Comment: Usually you should not change the version number manually. Either using maven-release-plugin or versions-maven-plugin to change the versions...that makes it easier...